# Automatic translate transform with respect to borders in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, translate

I need to have my `TextBox` translated by the vector, say `X = 10, Y = 10` , when the  `TextBox` is placed in the top left corner of my window.
However, if it's situated in the right bottom corner, it should be translated by the vector `X = -10, Y = -10`.

I wonder, if it is possible to set the translate transform for a certain control according to its position (bottom-right/left / top-right/left) by a quick hack.

Do you have any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have two property XValue and YValue, based on the orientation you need to coerce the value using CoerceValueCallback of the dependency property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback.aspx
HTH